# traitCollectionDidChange is failing second time it is called

Tags: ios

I have the following `traitCollectionDidChange`.

```
- (void) traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection{
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];

    if (previousTraitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass){
        NSInteger horizontalClass = self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass;
        NSInteger verticalClass = self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass;
        switch(horizontalClass){
            case UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact:
                if (verticalClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular){
                    // Setup for iPhone
                }
                break;
            case UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular:
                if (verticalClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular){
                    // Setup for iPad
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`Update`: It fails even when just turning the iPad. Anytime the methode is getting called again it fails with: `if (previousTraitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass){` is giving an error: [NSConcreteNotification horizontalSizeClass]: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. As the `previousTraitCollection` is `nil`.

Do you know why it is failing the second time?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will post this as it might spin off some discussions regarding supporting iOS 7.

The error was all created by me. I was trying at some earlier point to support iOS 7 and added the following in ViewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(traitCollectionDidChange:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

That is fair enough, then it will get called with no parameters 2 times.

My plan was to use this approach to look for the iOS version in ViewDidLoad and then add to or leave out from the NotificationCenter depending on iOS version 8 or not - apparently this will not work.

I might need some macro to add or leave out `traitCollectionDidChange` when running iOS 7.

Well, this was the problem - feel free to comment on iOs issue.

Thanks